# How to download multiple files using a script

Tags: command-line, downloads

I have to download multiple files from [here](http://tinyos-main.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release_tinyos_2_1_2/) in googlecode. Currently I open each folder and download each file by saving it using my browser. Is there a way to automatically download all folder/files?

Comment: Why not simply use a SVN client? Or Git since TinyOS moved to Github? Github even lets you download whole branches and tags as zip archive: https://github.com/tinyos/tinyos-main/archive/release_tinyos_2_1_2.zip

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`wget` is the command line utility you want:

```
wget -r http://tinyos-main.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release_tinyos_2_1_2/
```

It downloads everything in:

`http://tinyos-main.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release_tinyos_2_1_2/`

and all subdirectories - folder(s) and file(s) - in `release_tinyos_2_1_2/`

---

**Further Reading**:

- [GNU Wget 1.15 Manual: Top](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/index.html)

**Home Page**:

- [GNU Wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/)

Comment: Thanks, this look like a nice solution, but before I start the download, can you please tell me where these files will be saved?

Comment: they will be saved in your current directory.

Comment: in the directory you are in. Usually in your home directory. try this 'mkdir tinyos" to create a folder called 'tinyos' and the 'cd tinyos' cd go in the folder then run the command it will download everything in that folder.

Comment: OMG I think this command is downloading everything in this subdomain, not only the folder I wanted but everything else!

Comment: I mean it dowloaded everything inside /svn/ folder. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: /svn/???  remove /svn/*.* with root nautilus like so 'gksudo nautilus' then got to '/svn/'? then remove all downloaded content and then again run this in terminal 'cd' then 'mkdir tinyos' and then cd 'tinyos' and the the command 'wget -r http://tinyos-main.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release_tinyos_2_1_2/'

Answer (score -1):

In Ubuntu terminal try this using `wget`

```
wget -r -i http://XXXX/XXX/XX
```

But if you have a specific file type then

```
wget -r -l1 -A.txt https://xxxx/pub/data/xx/products/xx/2012/
```

`.txt` is the file extension